# The scroll bar is being designed using jscrollpane.js. However, as I use this on the sidebar, I can't see the screen

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

The scroll bar is being designed using jscrollpane.js. However, as I use this on the sidebar, I can't see the screen. What's the problem? It seems to make the width:0px; height:0px;

link :

http://designderjadu.dothome.co.kr/mintest/index.html

Comment: Can you please explain in detail. Because I can see the screen.  You just need to add CSS in you code #chatMessageBox { padding-bottom: 120px; }. So, content will show properly.

Comment: In the link I showed you, you can see the sidebar on the left side of the screen by dragging the mouse over it. I'd like you to look at this part from the Source View.

<div class="sub_depth depth01>
<div id="scroll_custom">
~
[sub_depth class] contains the contents. 
However, when jscrollpane.js is inserted as follows, the screen is not visible while processing the contents of sub_depth.

$(function() {
$('#scroll_custom')jScrollPane();
});

Comment: You should try this plugin: http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/scrollbar_themes_demo.html